# How to switch tab programmatically in react-navigation showing the animation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using the `MaterialTopTabNavigationProp`, and need to change the selected tab programmatically. 
I just tried using `navigation.navigate` or `navigation.jumpTo`, everything works fine, but the changing is instant with no animation, is there a way to show the classic tab switching animation?

Thanks everyone

Comment: @fixedDrill this is not true in case of programmatically jump

Answer (score -1):

If you want animation when you change the tab, you can use the following library.

[react-native-animated-tabbar](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-animated-tabbar)